# send dynamic argument in include file

Tags: php

there are unpredictable lengths of arguments in the `view` function:

```
class My_Controller {
    public function view()
        {
            $variables = func_get_args()
            include $variables[0];
        }
}

class autoload extends My_Controller {
    function homePage ()
        {
            $this->view('home.php', $oneData, $twoData, $threeData)
            //the arguments lengths is unpredictable here;
        }
}
```

How to pass the argument `$oneData`, `$twoData`, `$threeData` in the include statement without statically declaring it in the `function view ()` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what your include statement is doing. However, it is possible to pass your variables to view if you change your view function to accept an array of values.

```
class My_Controller {
    public function view($viewFile, $arrValues)
        {
            print_r($arrValues);
            foreach ($arrayValues as $variableName=>$variableValue) {
                echo "The value for variable $variableName is $variableValue \n";
            }
        }
}

class autoload extends My_Controller {
    function homePage ()
        {
            $this->view('home.php', array(
               'oneData'   => $oneData,
               'oneData'   => $twoData,
               'threeData' => $threeData)
            //the arguments lengths is unpredictable here;
        }
}
```

Comment: it only prints the `home.php`. Any idea, please? thanks in advance.

Comment: and also, I need the variable names not the values of the variables itself, in order to pass it again to the include line.

Comment: @iyal, I added a parameter for the view file that was missing and added an example to show the variable name and its value. Please refer to my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Only functions can accept parameters, files cannot.
Put your actual logic in a function and call that function in your `view()` after included the file.

Comment: $oneData, $twoData, $threeData are not files. they are variables passing  to the `home.php`. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: if I can call it in another function dynamically, then I won't need another function?

Answer (score -1):

Try with `file_put_contents`

```
class My_Controller {
    public function view()
        {
            $variables = func_get_args()
            call_user_func_array('file_put_contents',$variables);
        }
}

class autoload extends My_Controller {
    function homePage ()
        {
            $this->view('home.php', $oneData, $twoData, $threeData)
            //the arguments lengths is unpredictable here;
        }
}
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: file put contents expect parameter 3 with long, array given?